# Getting collection from foreign key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In such a two tables

```
table Person
{
    int Id -> primary key
    varchar name
    varchar nick
    int GroupId -> foreign key
}

table Group
{
    int Id -> primary key
    varchar name
}
```

If I use

```
var result = (from c in myDataBase.Group
             select c).ToList<Group>();
```

I get only list of Group, but field `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Person>` is empty. How should I change query to get also list of Persons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with:

```
myDataBase.Group.Include("Person").Select(a => a).ToList();
```

Btw: what is equivalent of `Include()` in linq query `from...where...select` ?

Comment: `from a in myDataBase.Group.Include("Person") select a;` is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where `System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Person>` has to be, but I *presume* you are searching for [Inner join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx)

```
  var query = from person in people
                join group in groups on person.GroupId equals group .Id
                select new {.. something... };
```

Here I *presumed* you have somewhere `people` (collection of `Person`  types) and want to find all persons from that collection and their matching information from related  `Group`.

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: Hm, why I get inproperly results? I mean counter in collection of persons still is 0 (the same query in sql management studio shows correct result ie one row).

Comment: When I use it first time I got counter = 1.. But now something's wrong. Database is the same, rows are the same

Comment: @Saint: you can use [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) and run your LINQ query inside it. After you can switch to SQL tab, and see what SQL was *actually* generated by the LINQ-TO-SQL query, and naturally can compare with SQL query you say works.